# How can I be sure calling `String.Index.advancedBy` won't cause a crash?

Tags: string, swift

Calling `advancedBy` on a `String.CharacterView.Index` will cause an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if the distance to advance by is too large. This can be seen here:

```
let inputString = "Hello, world!"
let index = inputString.startIndex
let distance = 100
let newIndex = index.advancedBy(distance) // fatal error: cannot increment endIndex
```

Now, what if `index` had already been advanced from the string's `startIndex` some unknown number of times, and `distance` was some unsafe user input? How can I verify advancing the index by the given distance won't cause a crash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use method advancedBy(n: Self.Distance, limit: Self) and set inputString endIndex as the limit:

```
let newIndex = index.advancedBy(distance, limit: inputString.endIndex)
```

Comment: So I can, not sure how I missed that while looking the `advancedBy` API details!